# How to get "Pinching" in Openlayers working on Android?

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile, android

If you go to [THIS OpenLayers Mobile example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile.html) on android you'll notice that "*pinching*" for zooming does not work. But it works for iPhone and iPad.

Anyone know how i can get "*pinching*" to work on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known flaw in most Android **2.x** browsers, they do not handle multi-touch events.

I know that Opera Mobile for Android does handle multitouch, and thus pinch zoom, but none of the other browsers I've tested (stock, dolphin, firefox)..

The best strategy is thus to nag on the browser vendors..

Answer (score 3):

You can now re-enable (or more accurately: polyfill) this Android 2.x most-wanted feature with the [WebView MultiTouch Polyfill (WMP)](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill) .

This will of course only help if you are developing your own HTML5-app or simply want a multi-touch enabled webkit browser (meaning the stock browser) that you can use to test mobile multitouch apps.

I have just tested the OpenLayers Mobile Example link that was provided above on my phone running 2.3.3 with WMP, pinch-zooming & double-tap work like a charm.